# How to make Hyper-V not change the MAC of the default switch on every boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v, mac-address, hyper-v-manager

Hyper-V changes the MAC-Address of its "vEthernet (Default Switch)" on every Windows boot.

I can manually set it back in the "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter Properties" under Advanced/Network Address after every boot but i'm looking for a way to tell Hyper-V to use a static MAC or the last used MAC instead.

I believe [this guy here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0dc1c46a-25a5-4476-8005-709532df414b/mac-address-of-hosts-hyperv-network-adapter-changes) has a similar problem.

Comment: AFAIK, the Default switch is not customizable and has no significance for the Windows host - it's sole purpose is to provide a virtual internet link between the WAN connected interface on the Windows host and the Default adapter in order to provide internet access to a client VM.

Comment: @JW0914 I have a very old SW whose License is mac address based and which checks the first adapter of the host and unfortunately this is the Hyper-Vs' default switch.

Comment: you may be able to modify what Windows considers the first adapter via the registry. Is it simply going off the first letter in the adapter's name _(i.e. would renaming the Default adapter to `vDefault` work)_? If the latter works, you'll have to rename it after every bi-annual update or whenever a Hyper-V update is pushed